# How do I post a form with radio buttos in cURL?

Tags: php, curl, post

Form in the server site contains one text box and two radio buttons and a submit button. This is waht I tried. Please help.

[image]

```
        $url = "Url goes here";

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"postcode\":\"3150\", \"customerType\":\"Residential\",\"fuelType\":\"Electricity\"}");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
            echo "test";
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
        echo "</pre>";

        curl_close($ch);
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: you post the value of the element, just like any other element. They're parameters. Try to divorce that from the form part - you're not using the form, you're using cURL. The form is just a way to generate a HTTP request. What you want to emulate is the HTTP request generated by the form. You can use your browser's developer tools to see what request the form generates, and then you can write some cURL to generate a request in the same format.

Comment: A very obvious problem above is that you're trying to submit (escaped) JSON in a single string, rather than separate parameters. Curl will let you specify individual parameters. I think you haven't understood the data formats you're using, or read the cURL documentation to understand how to specify individual parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It works like for a text value.

Find the name of these radio, check the value you want.

Example :

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other  
</form>
```

Your cURL Postfield should looks like this :

```
$data = array('gender' => 'male');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```